# Herpes: would prophylaxis H202 3% or alchol 70% decrease risk of infection from exposure?

Tags: herpes, antiseptics, prophylaxis

If someone was to kiss someone else with herpes, would approximately 3% H2O2 or 70% alcohol offer a proven risk reduction immediately after an exposure (within the hour for instance)?

I'm looking for [reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers).

Comment: Someone would have to do clinical study to answer that question, and I very much doubt they have. I also doubt that it would help avoid infection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you don't think it would help?

Comment: A mouth-to-mouth kiss exchanges body fluids. There's no undoing that.

Comment: Interesting idea.  But if the virus remained on the surface of the lips, or within the mouth, but hadn't been absorbed by mouth tissues, then I'm figuring it would prevent infection, and it wouldn't infect lower down the GI track.  Are you thinking that infection usually occurs inside several minutes?  Or that herpes isn't vulnerably to those antiseptics?

Comment: Those antiseptics most likely kill herpes virus, but whether they could reach every virus in the mouth and esophagus in sufficient concentration before it was able to infect isn't as likely. Comments aren't for extended discussions so I'd need to write an answer to really address this and I don't quite have time for that right now.

Answer (score 1):

Both alcohols, ethyl and isopropyl, can kill several bacteria in 10 seconds or fewer in the lab, including Staph aureus, Strep pyogenes, E. coli, Salmonella typhosa, and Pseudomonas species, some of the bad actors in infections. For M. tuberculosis, it may take as long as five minutes of contact.  Many, but not all, viruses are goners, too, like HIV, hepatitis B, herpes, influenza, etc. Even some systemic bad fungal infections are susceptible, but again not all. But kissing means you put the virus into the mucose of the Respiratory and GI tract,  rubbing the alcohol wont help the disease transmission.

Some references:
- [This study is addressing the effectiveness of alcohol](http://www.academia.edu/32253904/Effectiveness_of_disinfection_with_alcohol_70_w_v_of_contaminated_surfaces_not_previously_cleaned).
- [This PDF](http://www.mtpinnacle.com/pdfs/disinfectant-selection-guidelines.pdf)

Comment: Here is my resource, you may googling the pdf : Effectiveness of disinfection with alcohol 70% (w/v) of contaminated surfaces not previously cleaned . Here are the writers :Maurício Uchikawa Graziano1 Kazuko Uchikawa Graziano2 Flávia Morais Gomes Pinto3 Camila Quartim de Moraes Bruna3 Rafael Queiroz de Souza4 Cesar Angelo Lascala5

Comment: http://www.mtpinnacle.com/pdfs/disinfectant-selection-guidelines.pdf here you may find the best antiseptic for herpes prophylaxis. Enjoy

Comment: I am not really good answering questions in English, so i am sorry. I got the answer that herpes can be prophylaxed by antiseptic in this guidelines http://www.mtpinnacle.com/pdfs/disinfectant-selection-guidelines.pdf

Comment: http://www.academia.edu/32253904/Effectiveness_of_disinfection_with_alcohol_70_w_v_of_contaminated_surfaces_not_previously_cleaned This is a link to the study. Maybe include both links you found in your answer? I can not upvote unless you [edit] it.

Comment: Sorry iam new at this. i dont know how to edit. Sorryy

Comment: @Narusan I voted to accept your edit but it still needs one more vote.